# Exchange 2013 Relay Permissions

Tags: permissions, exchange

I'm trying to set up a receive connector that will allow a web based CRM to relay mail. So far, it works, but only if the user I use to login is in the group "Domain Admins" in active directory.

Here are the settings I have checked for the receive connector:

- Security - Authentication: Transport Layer Security, Basic
  Authentication
- Security - Permission Groups: Exchange Users, Anonymous Users
- Scoping - IP Addresses: Addresses of the CRM, and my IP address for
  testing purposes.
- Scoping - Network Adapter Bindings: All available IPv4, Port 25.

And here's the steps I'm going through to send an email:

```
telnet (server fqdn) 25  
ehlo   
auth login    
(username in base 64)    
(password in base 64)
"Authentication successful"
mail from: (email address)
"sender ok"
rcpt to: (my email addres)
"recipient ok"
data
subject: test
test
.
"250 Mail queued for delivery."
quit
```

And I never get the email, it doesn't show up in the queue, or in the SMTP logs. But if I add the user to the "Domain Admins" group in Active Directory Users and Computers, and repeat these steps, everything looks exactly the same, but I do receive the email. Currently, the test user is only a member of "Domain Users". Any ideas?

Comment: Does your CRM send email only from its own account, or does it send on behalf of other users (ie pretending to be those users)?

Comment: Sends on behalf of other users, I need to supply it with credentials to the Exchange server.

Comment: Is the email address to which you're sending part of your Exchange system, or is it an external address? If it's external what happens when you try to send to a local Exchange email address?

Comment: I had been trying to send to an external address. I just now tried to send to a local Exchange address and it's doing the same thing -  "250 mail queued for delivery." but it doesn't go through, nothing in the queue, no bounceback, not in junk/spam firewall.

Comment: This allows an email to be sent without doing Auth Login, but if I do auth login, then send the email, it's still doing the same thing (says it's queued but never gets delivered unless I make user a domain admin). The CRM requires that Auth Login be used.

Comment: Ah OK. If you must authenticate then you need to add these two permissions to the account, too: Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Sender,
Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Authoritative-Domain-Sender.

Comment: Still doing the same thing where the email will only go through if user is a domain admin. Here's the command I ran: 

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ReceiveConnector "Relay" | Add-ADPermission -User "domain\user" -ExtendedRights "Ms-Exch-
SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient", "Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Sender", "Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Authoritative-Domain-Sender"

Comment: SOLVED: I got it figured out. Opened wireshark on the mail server, and it was giving a "550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender\r\n", so I went into the ECP > Recipients > Edit "recipient name" > mailbox delegation > Add Send As > and I added the user, giving it send as permissions to its own mailbox. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already configured the transport connector that's specific to your CRM; that's good. You've got "Anonymous users" ticked? That will allow your CRM system to send on behalf of your local users.

Now, assuming the connector is called "CRM", also run this powershell snippet

```
Get-ReceiveConnector "CRM" | Add-ADPermission -User "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" -ExtendedRights "Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient"
```

What this does is to tell Exchange that your CRM system is to be permitted to use Exchange to relay through it to non-local users. (I don't recall whether this was required on my 2010 system to deliver to local users, too, but I do recall plenty of frustration on this matter. So much so that my notes became incomplete as I tried one thing after another.)

This link to [Elan Shudnow's blog post](http://www.shudnow.net/2013/06/04/how-anonymous-relay-works-in-exchange-2013/) on the matter may also help.